# Record a medium-quality video (android)

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

So I faced a problem of recording a video of not very high quality so that I can upload it to server. 
I cannot use standard intent option, cause it only supports 2 types of quality: best and awful. I need something in the middle.
I tried to build an activity with MediaRecorder but failed to make it work on some low-end devices which I don't have access to. I've got "RuntimeError: start failed" on those devices and after a lot of research I realize that it's not likely that I will fix it and it's taking too much time (it's not the main feature of my app).
What are my options?
Maybe there's some kind of library for videorecording where somebody has already taken care of all the difficulties (but I really need to force user to make video of a small size). I'd be glad if someone pointed me into it if it exists.
Or maybe some other solution like compressing etc...
Thanks.

Comment: i am facing same problem i not want to upload video in High quality and also Low quality. I try to set Camera Profile CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_480P but app getting crash :(

Comment: @HiteshGehlot, yeah, I've also been fighting this problem. Different devices somewhy behave differently when you set recording parameters and profiles. At the moment I'm using the following library (although unfortunately it also has some bugs) https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera

Comment: i resolved my problem tomorrow i will give you answer

Comment: @HiteshGehlot any updates on your solution for this?